# error while plotting stacked bar in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot stacked bar graph using gnuplot. As for example I tried to plot stacked bar graph using data and gnuplot code below:

Data is:

```
year foo bar rest
1900 20 10 20
2000 20 30 10
2100 20 10 10
```

The gnuplot code is:

```
#
# Stacked histograms
#
set term png size 300,300
set output 'stackedhisto.png'
#set title "Stacked histogram\nTotals"

# Where to put the legend
# and what it should contain
set key invert reverse Left outside
set key autotitle columnheader

set yrange [0:100]
set ylabel "total"

# Define plot style 'stacked histogram'
# with additional settings
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.75

# We are plotting columns 2, 3 and 4 as y-values,
# the x-ticks are coming from column 1
plot 'stackedhisto.dat' using 2:xtic(1) \
    ,'' using 3 \
    ,'' using 4
```

When I execute the above code I get some error which I dont know the source is. The error is as below:

```
./script-plot-total-stacked-bar.gnu: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./script-plot-total-stacked-bar.gnu: line 25: `plot 'stackedhisto.dat' using 2:xtic(1) \'
```

This error preventing me from plotting my own data. I am using gnuplot 4.6 in Ubuntu 11.10. 
Appreciate any help in advance.
Thanks

note : In fact this is published at [1](http://ajhaupt.blogspot.com/2010/12/gnuplot-stacked-histograms.html).

Answer (score 0):

I could correct this script. There is a typo error. I retyped the hyphen at line

```
plot 'stackedhisto.dat' using 2:xtic(1) \
    ,'' using 3 \
    ,'' using 4
```

Sorry for the error.